# Modeling geometric sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

enter image description here

I'm pretty sure I modeled the situation in the image right using a geometric sequence. If the puppy weighs $0.75$ lbs. at birth and his weight increases by $26\%$ every week, then an appropriate model would be $A_n=(0.75)(1.26)^{n-1}$, where $A_n$ is the weight of the puppy after $n$ weeks. But WebAssign says no.

Comment: I don't see an image, or even a link to an image. Did you remember to attach it?

Comment: This is a terrible title, and can be reduced in length by 80%.  You'll get more help if you do so.

Comment: Thanks, David. This is my first time using StackExchange.

Comment: What will the weight of the puppy be after one week?

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that as you are counting weeks it should be $A_n=0.75\cdot 1.26^{(n-1)}$.  You are missing the parentheses in this post so the $-1$ is not in the exponent.  Were you missing them when you submitted the answer?  The other problem is where you start counting the weeks from.  If the week of birth is week $0$ it becomes $A_n=0.75\cdot 1.26^{n}$

Answer (score 0):

Your only error is to write $A^{n-1}$. In fact, in the week $0$, the puppy grows $0$, so the correct furmula is:
$$A_n=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\left(\frac{63}{50}\right)^n$$
So, at $n=0$, we have that:
$$A_0=\frac{3}{4}$$